# How I can generate 00001 in windows form in C# using Nested loop

Tags: c#

I try to code in Windows form to generate user Defined numer of digit which simes like this
00001
00002
...
00010
...
00100
etc that the digit is constant while the numbere will vary

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please, first try something by yourself and then if you got some problem, post here to get an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think, what you want, is much simpler:

```
Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("00000"));
```

Examples of input/output

```
// integer

number = 1;      // Outputs: 00001
number = 100;    // Outputs: 00100
number = 1234;   // Outputs: 01234
number = 12345;  // Outputs: 12345
number = 123456; // Outputs: 123456

number = -1;     // Outputs: -00001

// double

number = 0.05;   // Outputs: 00000    
number = 0.5;    // Outputs: 00001
number = 5.1;    // Outputs: 00005
number = 5.5;    // Outputs: 00006
number = 5.9;    // Outputs: 00006
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [number formatting with leading zeros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros)

Example

```
int num1 = 10;
var text1 = num1.ToString("D4"); //0010

int num2 = 500;
var text2 = num2.ToString("D6"); //000500
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the number to a string and then call `PadLeft` to pad it with zeroes:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= 99999; ++i)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(i.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'));
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I try to code in Windows form to generate **user Defined** numer of digit

You can take the number from the user and apply it to both Theraot's and Bahrom's answers:

```
int numberWidth = (int)numericUpDown1.Value; // get this from the user somehow
string format1 = new string('0', numberWidth);
string format2 = "D" + numberWidth.ToString();

int number = 100;
label1.Text = number.ToString(format1);
label2.Text = number.ToString(format2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into string before displaying.